# Django User form not showing up in the admin page

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to implement a simple register page, but all data doesn't show up in admin.

here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from registro.forms import UserForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
# Create your views here.


def registro(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():

            #user = user_form.save()
            #user.set_password(user.password)
            user_form.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(request,'registro/registro.html',{'user_form':user_form,'registered':registered})
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registro.models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')
        labels = {
            'first_name': 'Nombre',
            'last_name': 'Apellidos',
            'email': 'Correo Electrónico',
            'password': 'Contraseña'
        }

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'e.g. algo@unison.mx'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),


        }
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

and admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from registro.models import UserProfileInfo
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(UserProfileInfo)
```

and finally, my .html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    {% if registered %}
    <h1>¡Gracias por registrarse!</h1>
    {% else %}
      <h1>Registro</h1>
      <h3>Llene el siguiente formulario:</h3>
      <form class="form-group">
        <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ user_form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registrar">
        </form>
        {% endif %}
      </form>


  </div>
</div>
```

I don't get any errors, the only problem that I'm having is that every time I hit register, nothing happens in the admin site, nor does my page redirect to the "thank you for registering" page as it should. Any insight on my problem will be welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your user's info in UserProfilInfo in the admin site, you have to create this user object in your UserProfilInfo every time you create a user

```
def registro(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            UserProfileInfo.objects.create(
            user = user,
            )

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()

    return render(request,'registro/registro.html',{'user_form':user_form,'registered':registered}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried doing what you said, but I keep running into the same problem. Whenever I submit the form, I don't see a POST status on the terminal, so the data doesn't register in the admin page. Do have any idea of what this could mean? Thanks again :)